# Sequence whose limit inferior less than limit superior

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a$ and $b$ be two real number, where $a<b.$ Give an example of a sequence whose limit superior is $b$ and whose limit inferior is $a.$

I can think of one sequence

$(-1)^j$ where $j=1$ to infinity

But I am not sure how to make make it general for $a$ and $b.$

Comment: Your example alternates between endpoints of the interval $[-1,1]$. So just find a linear transformation $f$ that maps $[-1,1]$ onto $[a,b]$, and your new sequence would be $f((-1)^j)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x_n = {b+a\over 2} + (-1)^n{b-a \over 2}$.

Comment: Yes I think that will function.

Answer (score 2):

$a,b,a,b,a,b,\dots \ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: @Fernando Do you understand why this **fully** answers your question?

Comment: Not really I know a less then b but a and b are letters not numbers unless they stand for something beyond their meaningsfulness.

Comment: "but a and b are letters not numbers" Your question says otherwise.